# Storing a character in a string variable

Tags: c

I am basically coding in c.
I have a character pointer that points to a character. Is there an way to store this character pointed to by the character pointer in a string variable??
Because when I tried doing so using "strcpy" I got type mismatch error , because I am trying to store a character as a string in a string variable.

Comment: Can you share some code please? It would make the question easier to answer.

Comment: pls add a MCVE _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: There are no "string" variables in C, only `char *`, which are nicknamed "strings".  Therefore, you are going to have to rephrase what you mean by "string"

Comment: @snoopy-- there are no `string` _types_ in C, but there are strings, which are defined in the Standard to be null-terminated character arrays.

Comment: Are you following cs50?

Comment: And show code instead of describing code

Comment: @snoopy *only char *, which are nicknamed "strings".* This must have been the exact thought process that went into making *cs50.h*

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your pointer to character is s defined as

```
char *s;
```

You want to make it into a string.

```
char string[2];
string[0] = *s;
string[1] = '\0';
```

And you are set.

This will cause the string to have an automatic storage duration. You can choose to make it heap allocated or global scoped depending on your requirement. That I guess you already know.

Comment: Good answer, but personally I'd rather write `'\0'` for clarity and to avoid coercion.

Answer (score 1):

You can just dereference the pointer to get access to the character. I'm assuming you're working with C++ if you are using `string` types.

```
char* c = "z";
string s;
s += *c;
```

Comment: C, the question mentions C.

Comment: Since OP has C tag, they may be using `cs50.h` and that abominable `typedef char *string`, in which case `+=` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Character pointers *are* what we use for "string variables" in C.

In C a string is just an array of characters which ends with the character `\0`. You can either have a statically allocated array or a dynamically allocated array pointed to by a pointer. `strcpy` takes such a pointer.

Comment: In C a string is __not__ just an array of characters, a string is a null terminated array of characters.